# Suction Side vs. Pressure Side Pool Cleaner

Tags: pool

What is the difference/advantages/disadvantage of pressure side vs. suction side pool cleaners, and which one to get for a concrete pool?

Comment: The original title was "Suction vs. Pressure Pool Cleaner" and I believe it should stay, since you can use _either_ type for a "Concrete Pool".

Comment: Our preference is for titles to be in the form of a question. It results in better search engine hits so more people find your question in the future.